# Creating duplicate rows foreach row of another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have two tables foreach row of one table  need duplicate 6 rows of another table with the id of the first table. How to achieve this ? The two tables are as follows and i am using codeigniter framework. I am intentionally not pasting the MVC code as i dont want to confuse you guys. Please find the reference at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977815/foreach-id-create-duplicate-rows-in-another-mysql-table-codeigniter. I have attached the two tables FYR

[image]

[image]

Input is the above table and output should be the below table. I am unable to create duplicate rows foreach resignation request i.e foreach row in pr_resignation_requests table

[image]

Comment: Show what you want based on sample input and expected output

Comment: I have edited my question